# iPhone Application – Card Corner Detection in Camera Implementation

Tags: iphone, ios, opencv, camera, detection

I am trying to implement a Card Scanner to scan front and back of License Card images in an iphone App. I would like to implement exact same logic as the Lemon App ([www.lemon.com](http://www.lemon.com/)) in which as soon as you place a card within 4 corners, the camera autosnaps the picture and does some processing in the background. Any ideas on how to implement the same?

Any Open Source library or an API available to implement this quickly?

Comment: Man, you just gave away a good(?) app idea. Why do you think somebody who knows the answer would answer your question instead of developing it himself?

Comment: @david - Hi david. You r right and Thank you for that comment :) . I was trying to find a solution for this for past few days. But can't find one. So I thought it will be better to ask here rather than keeping my idea without implementing. I am a beginner in iOS development and need to learn new things. Not bothered about someone taking my idea that I am unable to implement. If you can do this, I appreciate to do the same, but please share to me after you complete. Then I can try another idea

Comment: I am not willing to steal your idea but I was wondering why you throw away yours.

Comment: I got a sample code. But till can't make a solution for mine. http://www.hatzlaha.co.il/150842/FAST-Corner-V2 Can anyone help to use this for my need?